# PHP - Eval() not working

Tags: php

My code isn't working, what am i doing wrong?

Its a very simple and small script

```
<textarea name="codebtn" id="code"></textarea> 
<input name="code" type="submit" /> 
</form> 
<br> 

Result 
<br> 
<?php 


if(isset($_POST["code"])) { 

$lol = $_POST["codebtn"];

eval('?>' . $lol .'<?php'); 

} 

?>
```

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: How is it "not working"?  What happens?  Why are you doing `'?>' . $lol .'<?php'`?  Why not just `echo $lol;`?  Why are you using `eval`?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure whether to `$lol` at this or be scared that your trying to pass user input to `eval()`

Comment: @Boldewyn - Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!

Comment: Also, you are aware that this is in no way safe, right?  What if I typed in something like `<?php unlink('index.php'); ?>` or `<?php exec('rm -rf /*'); ?>`?  Or worse‽

Comment: @j08691 https://twitter.com/m_strehl/status/461142376959197184 (great minds think alike ☺)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `eval`, and everything to do with your form.

Because `<input name="code" />` has no `value` attribute, it is not being sent as part of the request, thereby causing `isset($_POST["code"])` to fail.

Try:

```
<input type="submit" name="code" value="lol" />
```

As an aside, what's wrong with `echo $lol` instead of eval?

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining the beginning of form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="codebtn" id="code"></textarea> 
<input name="code" type="submit" /> 
</form>
```